# Definition of Dirac mass : $\delta (A)=1$ if $0\in A$ and $0$ otherwise or $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta (dx)=f(0)$

Tags: measure-theory

The way I define $\delta $ mass is $$\delta (A)=\begin{cases}1&0\in A\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

However, in my lecture of measure, they define it as $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta (dx)=f(0).$$

Are both definition the same ? If using one definition rather than an other ?

Comment: The first is some version of the *Kronecker* delta, i.e. an indicator function, whereas the *Dirac* delta "function" is a measure or distribution, the "derivative" of the Heaviside function.

Comment: Your statement miss information (-1 for an incomplete statement). Which kind of function if $f$ ? which kind of set is $A$ ? I guess $f$ is measurable, and $A$ is Borel set. Then, both are equivalents. Use approximation with simple function to prove the equivalence of both definiton.

Comment: @Surb: Sorry to have been unclear. Could you be more precise on why both definitions are equivalents ?

Comment: 1. Both definitions of $\delta$ are equivalent.  2. The Dirac measure ($\delta$)  is also defined in $\sigma$-algebra $2^{\Bbb R}$ (and, consequently, in any $\sigma$-algebra defined in $\Bbb R$). Both definitions of $\delta$ remains equivalent in $2^{\Bbb R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose your first definition.**

**Step 1:** Suppose $f$ is simple, i.e. $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}.$ Since, at most one $A_i$ contain $0$, $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta (\mathrm d x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\delta (A_i)=f(0).$$

**Step 2:** If $f\geq 0$ there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple function s.t. $f_n\nearrow f$. The claim follow using Monotone convergence theorem.

**Step 3:** If $f$ is measurable, then write it as $f^+-f^-$ where $f^+(x)=f(x)\vee 0$ and $f^-(x)=-(f(x)\wedge 0)$, and apply the Step 2. The second definition follows.

---

**Suppose your second definition**

In particular, if $A$ is measurable, then so is $f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_A(x)$. Therefore $$\delta (A)=\int_{A}\delta (\mathrm d x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_A(x)\delta (\mathrm d x)=f(0)=\begin{cases}1&0\in A\\ 0&0\notin A\end{cases}.$$
The first definition follows.

---

**Remark** Measurability of the function and of the set can be understood as Borel-measurable or Lebesgue-measurable.